# Postgresql, connection only with ssl

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I have a Postgresql database with this string in the postgresql.conf file:

> ssl = on
>   ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
>   ssl_key_file = 'server.key'

In the pg_hba.conf file i have ONLY this host in IPv4:

> hostssl  all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

With these settings I would like to connect only with ssl, instead I also connect without. Why? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: That cannot be your complete `pg_hba.conf` file. There must be another entry that allows the connection (or you changed the file and didn't reload).

Comment: No, this is all:
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
hostssl  all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

Comment: Either you didn't reload the server, or the reload failed (check the log), or you edited the wrong file.

Comment: Using "select * from pg_hba_file_rules ;" will show you definitively what rules that instance of PostgreSQL is actually using, as opposed to what rules you think it is using.  Also, you specifically mention IPv4, what about IPv6?

Comment: The select * from pg_hba_file_rules query confirms that there is only the hostssl line, but I connect without problems even without SSL.
I've never used the IPv6 protocol, but I don't think it's important in this situation, am I wrong?